# Android getActivity().setTitle() gets String field from wrong object in ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I wish to set the titlebar in this fragment's activity to the HelpItem's description field.

On line 10, I set the title of the activity with a String representing a HelpItem's description.

Instead of getting the description of the retrieved HelpItem on line 9 I get the description of the next HelpItem.

I.E. in an ArrayList of five HelpItem objects with the helpDescriptions "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" clicking on "bbb" in the 
list displays "bbb" and the information text associated with it.  The title is set to "ccc".

On line 19 the same call to `helpItem.getHelpDescription()` returns the description field of the "bbb" object.

When moving through the list via a ViewPager the next object in the list has the same issue until I reach the end of the list,

where the correct helpDescription field is displayed.  I can also move back to the start of the list and it will display the correct

helpDescription, but this is then lost when I move forward and backward through the list again.

Any ideas why this is happening?  Thanks.

```
 public class HelpFragment extends Fragment {

 private HelpItem helpItem;
 private TextView mHelpDetails;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    UUID helpItemId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_HELP_ITEM_ID);
    helpItem = HelpList.get(getActivity()).getHelpItem(helpItemId);
    getActivity().setTitle(helpItem.getHelpDescription());
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View userView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help_item, parent, false);

    mHelpDetails = (TextView) userView.findViewById(R.id.help_details);
    String displayInfo = "";

    if ((helpItem.getHelpDescription() != null) && 
        (helpItem.getHelpInformation() != null)) {

            displayInfo = helpItem.getHelpDescription() + "\n\n\n" + 
                          helpItem.getHelpInformation();
            mHelpDetails.setText(displayInfo);

            Log.d(TAG, "3 " + helpItem.getHelpDescription() + " " 
                            + helpItem.getHelpInformation());
    }

    return userView;

    }
 }
```

..

```
public class HelpItem {

private UUID mId;
private String helpDescription;
private String helpInformation;

public HelpItem(String hDesc, String hInfo) {
    mId = UUID.randomUUID();        
    helpDescription = hDesc;
    helpInformation = hInfo;
}

public UUID getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    mId = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return helpDescription;
}

public String getHelpDescription() {
    return helpDescription;
}

public void setHelpDescription(String hDescription) {
    this.helpDescription = hDescription;
}

public String getHelpInformation() {
    return helpInformation;
}

public void setHelpInformation(String hInformation) {
    this.helpInformation = hInformation;
}

}
```

..

```
public class HelpListItemPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ArrayList<HelpItem> mHelpList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    mHelpList = HelpList.get(this).getHelpList();

    FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragManager) {
        @Override           
        public int getCount() {
            return mHelpList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            HelpItem hItem = mHelpList.get(position);
            return HelpFragment.newInstance(hItem.getId());
        }
    });

    UUID helpItemId = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(HelpFragment.EXTRA_HELP_ITEM_ID);

    for (int i = 0; i < mHelpList.size(); i++) {
        if (mHelpList.get(i).getId().equals(helpItemId)) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should post related class and method.

Comment: Instead of putting the whole code, just put the relevant code.